# how to remove duplicates in an inner join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

my query:

```
  select 
  SUM(payments.paid_amt) as paid_amt, 
  SUM(payments.copay_amt) as copay_amt,
  SUM(payments.CO_INSURANCE_AMT) as co_ins_amt,
  SUM(payments.PATIENT_RESP_AMT) as patient_resp_amt,
  accession.ACCESSION_ID

  from 
  [F_PAYOR_PAYMENTS_monthly] payments

  join F_ACCESSION_daily accession
  on accession.ACCESSION_ID=payments.ACCESSION_ID

  where accession.XIFIN_LOAD_DATE between '20111201' and '20111231'

  group by   accession.ACCESSION_ID
```

here is a sample of the accession data:

[image]

and here are the payments:

[image]

my problem is the SAME payment for the SAME accession is being counted multiple times

my question is how do i make sure that payments for a specific accession are summed only once?

the relationship between `payments ---> accession` is `many to 1`

thanks so much for your guidance.

what i am expecting for the above example is:

```
AA895325, sum(paid_amt), sum(copayt_amt), etc..
```

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results. If all you post is a query and a word problem, you're just going to get a bunch of follow-up questions asking for clarity.

Comment: Please provide an example of data to explain what is going wrong.  It is not obvious what you mean by "is returning duplicate payments for many accessions", since you are not returning anything at the payment level.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, i am summing all the payments corresponding to one particular accession

Comment: That still doesn't help. Can you please *read* the suggestions above. Completely.

Comment: @AaronBertrand i included sample data

Comment: @AaronBertrand my problem is the SAME payment for the SAME accession is being counted multiple times

Comment: This doesn't seem right, on the payments table there are no more columns?, a date? or a month? or something else?, or is just a table with multiple values for payments per accesion_id? (hint: that doesn't seem likely)

Comment: Aye but it's useless as they are ll in the same month, and you still haven't told us waht answer you would be expecting from it!

Comment: @Lamak the dates are there, i didnt want to show anymore due to privacy issues

Comment: In addition to showing the results you expect from the data displayed in the screen shot (probably the worst way to present sample data), it would also be helpful if the data from the two tables could actually be combined in the query you posted. Is there a single row where `accession.accession_id = payments.accession_id`? NO.

Comment: You already asked this [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089726/does-inner-join-exclude-duplicates/11089826#11089826).

Comment: i apologize that am i not explaining this clearly enough, i am trying my best

Comment: You asked this question yesterday. Did you not bother to read any of the answers that were posted there?

Comment: the question is actually different this time

Comment: You only need a month of payments?, group by month?. It really seems like a simple problem, either you filter a month from payments or you group by month (from payments)

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов, perhaps you should create some sample data that will allow us to help you without compromising the privacy of the data. Post the structure of the tables (`CREATE TABLE` statements) and a few `INSERT` statements for each table, that end up generating the "incorrect" results that you are finding. Then post what you actually want the results to look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, If I understand correclty your problem, it seems like a very simple concept that you are not taking into account. Of course the table that has the payments has more than one payment per `accesion_id`, even the name of the table gives a hint on that (`F_PAYOR_PAYMENTS_monthly`), you even said in your comments that that table has payments per month. So, knowing that, why it surprises you that you get multiple payments per `accesion_id`?, it seems obvious enough. Since you are not answering some comments asking you what payment should you choose, you either filter one month, or group by month, as simple as that:

```
select  accession.ACCESSION_ID,
        SUM(payments.paid_amt) as paid_amt, 
        SUM(payments.copay_amt) as copay_amt,
        SUM(payments.CO_INSURANCE_AMT) as co_ins_amt,
        SUM(payments.PATIENT_RESP_AMT) as patient_resp_amt

from [F_PAYOR_PAYMENTS_monthly] payments
join F_ACCESSION_daily accession
on accession.ACCESSION_ID=payments.ACCESSION_ID
where accession.XIFIN_LOAD_DATE between '20111201' and '20111231'
AND payment.[Month] = '201112'
group by   accession.ACCESSION_ID, payments.[Month]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some possibilities (this is not really an answer, but it is too long for a comment):

(1) You have duplicates in the tables.  Given that you are seeing duplicates, this would be the most obvious place to look.

(2) Your statement "my problem is the SAME payment for the SAME accession is being counted multiple times" is not quite correct.  The problem is that extra payments are being counted.  I am thinking that the payments have a payment date on them, and you are expecting the date logic at the accession level to catch it.  But this logic will still let in all payments.

(3) You are incorrect in your analysis that multiple payments are being recorded.  The query is correct, but not doing what you expect for some reason.

As written, the query should not be increasing payments, unless there are duplicate accession ids in the accession table.

Answer (score 1):

Take accession_id out of the select and the group by. It's summing by accession because you told it to.

Saying that seeing as you are grouping by Month and Year parts of XIFIN_LOAD_DATE, I would have expected them in the select list as well.

Having now read the above comments, I begin to be thoroughly confussed.

If you are summing by accession, and it's one to many, then more than one accession isn't a duplicate. It's what you said you wanted.

If you want to sum by the Year/Month of accession date, then removing accession-id should make it sum all the accessions based on what year/month the linked date is in.

It would help all concerned it you just did a bit of example data for input, and then list out what results you expect for the query.

Comment: tony thanks so much for this. my problem is the SAME payment for the SAME accession is being counted multiple times

Comment: tony, i do not need it to be summed by accession. i've taken out the LOAD DATE from the select.

Comment: Then why is ACCESSION_ID in the SELECT list???

Comment: Make your mind up. You commented on your question that you did! There's no way you are getting duplicates from that query by accession_id, unless you have the same payment in teh payments table more than once, and my question would be how do you know they are being duplicated. What are you comparing the query result to? Because if it's coming up with a different number, what it's doing different, might be what they call in our trade, a clue! Take some deep breaths, have a smoke, sleep on it. There's some unwarranted assumption cluttering up your thoughts.